# My wordpress homepage is not showing proper title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my wordpress site I set my homepage to be my latest posts and when it gets loaded title doesn't show like "Home - SiteName" but only " - SiteName".

How to fix this. I want to add Static "Home" in front or after "- SiteName"

Note:
1. I tried to check my home.php file but it is not there.
2. When I am saying "title" I mean the name or description shows in browser's tab.

Thanks

Comment: Have you set home page as front page from setting page in admin panel?

Comment: No I chose show latest posts as my home page

Answer (score 0):

hi you can add this plugin and customize the TITLE as your requirement
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-title/screenshots/
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add code like this to your header.php

```
    <title><?php
    if (is_front_page()) {echo ' My wonderful Page title in here ';}
    else {echo wp_title('');}
    ?>
    </title>
```

It will put the echo text as your homepage title, and the post/page title as the title for the other pages.  Other WordPress code can be added into the php if you want something more comprehensive